# Variable doesn't exist error

Tags: error

I am stuck with a bit of code - is someone able to help with this? For the 8th line of code, I'm getting a variable doesn't exist error. I have been starting at this far too long, so cannot see what's wrong.

EDIT: I have now updated my code, and now I am getting another error for: `leadsToUpdateById.put(tmpLead);` it says incorrect signature.

public static void copyFirstCallDate(List triggerNew) {

```
    Map<Task,Id> leadIdsByTasks = new Map<Task,Id>();
    for (Task t : triggerNew) {
        if (t.Status == 'Completed') {
           leadIdsByTasks.put(t, t.WhoId); 
        }
    }

    Map<Id,Lead> leadsToUpdateById = new Map<Id,Lead>([SELECT Id, X1st_Call__c FROM Lead WHERE Id IN: leadIdsByTasks.values()]); 

    for (Task t : triggerNew) {
        if (leadIdsByTasks.containsKey(t)) {
            Id lId = leadIdsByTasks.get(t);
            Lead tmpLead = leadsToUpdateById.get(lId);
            tmpLead.X1st_Call__c = t.Closed_Date__c;
            leadsToUpdateById.put(tmpLead);
        }
    }
    if ( !leadsToUpdateById.values().isEmpty()) {
        update leadsToUpdateById.values();
    }
}
```

Tia

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to replace   `whoIds.getValues()`  by  `leadIdsByTasks.getValues()`.  Looks like you may have  refactored and forgot to change the name.

Comment: oh, and it should be `leadIdsByTasks.values()`

Comment: EDIT: I have now updated my code, and now I am getting another error for: `leadsToUpdateById.put(tmpLead); `it says incorrect signature.

Comment: Put requires two parameters. The key and value. Key should be the lead's ID.

Answer (score 1):

It should be, map requires key value pair.

leadsToUpdateById.put(tmpLead.id, tmpLead);

Comment: Cool. my first answer. Glad you solved it.

Comment: Lily, as you changed your question both answers are valid. Could you select either (to the left of it) as accepted answer so that it's indicated that this has been resolved ? I'd suggest you accept this answer as Sforce Ninja can use some reputation :-).